# Overriding estimatedItemSize for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with a flow layout and an estimatedItemSize: `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 120)`

How can I make sure that my cell is autosizing itself so if it's larger than 120, it displays correctly? Is it just a matter of making sure that there's a full chain of constrained subviews connected to the top and bottom or a function I can call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to the constraints. `estimatedItemSize` will be used if you have no `sizeForItemAt indexPath` override and your layout does not have `itemSize` defined, instead autosizing based on content. Constrain your subviews properly and it should work if I understand what your aim is.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing a bottom constraint on my bottom-most view which was the issue.